# NEED HELP - how to make an excerpt of the post clickable?

Tags: css, wordpress, blogs, posts, elementor

I am working in Wordpress, and I am using Elementor. Elementor has a native feature for the title of the posts and images to link to the post.

But if I add an excerpt text, it doesn't link to the post. It is not clickable. The read more button does, but not the excerpt of the post.

I am trying to create something like this: greatist.com Every post on their website is clickable - the excerpt, the title, and the image.

My excerpts are really short like on that website, and I would really like them to be clickable. I have absolutely no idea how to do this and I'm beginning to think it's not possible. I am using Hello Elementor theme.

I would deeply appreciate anyone's help. I just registered to ask this question.

Comment: Well you must know css and also you need one widget with a link to the post(featured image, title, ... . You can create :before pseudo element for that widget so it covers the whole section. This way you make the whole block clickable

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to save text as an photo and make it clickable or make a full section clickable.To do this try to use plugin called "Make Column Clickable Elementor".

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your website:

```
const postExcerpts = document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-posts .elementor-post .elementor-post__excerpt');

postExcerpts.forEach(postExcerpt => {
    const postUrl = postExcerpt.parentNode.querySelector('.elementor-post__title a').href;
    postExcerpt.addEventListener('click', () => {
        window.location.href = postUrl;
    });
});
```

This can be added using a `script` tag. Choose from the following options:

1. [Add this code as a `script` tag in your functions.php file](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-custom-javascript-to-your-wordpress-site--cms-34368#:%7E:text=2.2.%20Print%20Out,external%C2%A0.js%20files.), to be rendered at the end of the page (`wp_footer` action hook).
2. If you have Elementor Pro, use its built-in [Custom Code feature](https://elementor.com/help/custom-code-pro/) to add the code in a `script` tag to the end of the `body` tag.

It's recommended to add a pointer cursor so the user will know the excerpt is a link. This can be achieved by adding the following CSS to your `style.css` file.

```
.elementor-posts .elementor-post .elementor-post__excerpt {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```